# How to choose linux user account when logging in from browser (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When connecting to a linux instance from GCP console from within the browser window there's no option to select the linux user to connect with. It seems to default to google username, which seems to be created when an instance is created.

On the other hand, after creating SSH keys for the use with CLI platform tools on another machine, the linux user name created by using the user name of the account the SSH keys are created on. After this, loging in to the same instance as in para 1 above from the browser in console takes me to this newly created user. And again, there's no option to select the linux user-name loged in.

Tangentially, I tried to change the user name after loging in using `sudo -u [username]` but this did not work.

So, how to choose which linux user logs in from the GCP console using the browser?

Comment: Log into the web console as a different user, the ssh button uses your IAM account and transfers the keys to the instance.

Comment: I only have my own account as owner in the project, which contains the Linux instance. There's a bunch of @developer.gserviceaccount.com service accounts, which look like service accounts.